# jQuery Deferred/Promises with multiple SharePoint CAML Queries

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, promise, deferred, caml

Hi guys I have three async calls from three separate SharePoint lists with each query having a success callback which return objects and arrays. I want another function to execute after all three success callbacks return. I am not sure how to get this to work with jQuery deferreds. My codes is below. Please help me to understand how to use deferreds to achieve the objective above.

```
function managementMain() {
    //From here I want to call the third function after executing 
      the managementQuery function.
      outPutObj = managementQuery();
    //Execute some third function with outPutObj:
    third function(outPutObj);
}
function managementQuery() {
    //CAML definition 1 here.
    clContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { var soObj = onSOQuerySucceeded(); }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    //CAML definition 2 here.
    clContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { var poObj = onPOQuerySucceeded(); }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
   //CAML definition 3 here.
   clContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { var salesRepNamesList = onSalesRepNamesQuerySucceeded(); }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
   return {
       soObj: soObj,
       poObj: poObj,
       salesRepList: salesRepNamesList
   }
}
function onSOQuerySucceeded() {
     //Do something with the SharePoint List and return an object called soObj.
}
function onSalesRepNamesQuerySucceeded() {
     //Do something with the SharePoint List and return an array called salesRepNames.
}
function onPOQuerySucceeded() {
     //Do something with the SharePoint List and return an object called poObj.
}
```

The problem I'm having is that soObj, poObj and salesRepNamesList may not be returned by the time 
managementQuery function returns. So the outPutObj may be ill defined by the  time third function gets executed. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would essentially create 3 deferred objects, one for each async request. once the async request is done you would call the .resolve method on the deferred object

```
// query will return a promise
outputPromise = query();

// your third function needs to wait for the promise to resolve
// to ensure the wait, you use the .then() method on the promise above
outputPromise.then(function(outputObj) {
    thirdFunction(outputObj);
});

function query() {
    // Create deferred objects
    var deferred1 = $.Deferred();
    var deferred2 = $.Deferred();

    clContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { 
        var soObj = onSOQuerySucceeded();
        deferred1.resolve(soObj);
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        this.onQueryFailed();
        deferred1.reject();
    }));

    clContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { 
        var poObj = onPOQuerySucceeded();
        deferred2.resolve(poObj);
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
        this.onQueryFailed();
        deferred2.reject();
    }));

    // we must wait for all async ops to finish. to do this, we use the $.when() method
    // the $.when() method returns a promise that is resolved with the return
    // values of each deferred that was passed in. the then takes a callback
    // function and will spread each resolved value over the callback function's arguments
    return $.when(deferred1, deferred2).then(function(soObj, poObj) {
       // create the output object in the format you specified
       return {
           soObj: soObj,
           poObj: poObj
       }
    });
}
```

The jQ Deferred docs are here: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ in case you need to look something up

As a side note, I would highly recommend using another Promise library like bluebird or Q instead of jQuery's deferreds. They are compliant with the widely accepted [Promise/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) spec and the subsequent ES2015 Promise spec. jQ 3 will have a Promises/A+ compliant deferred, but the deferred pattern is not in ES2015 and it would behoove you to use the Promise pattern offered by those other libraries.

Comment: Hi nerdondon, I have accepted it as the correct answer. I don't have enough point at the moment for it to be publicly shown. Anyway, thanks very much for the very clear explanation and all the resources you provided. After trying for 2 days with all kind of deferred objects, now I got to understand how it works. Thanks!

Comment: hey no problem. i'm just glad it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the code is more complicated than it needs to be :

- You can purge `Function.createDelegate()` which is (a) not standard javascript, (b) not necessary because none of the functions to which it is applied uses `this`. Microsoft is a little naughty including `Function.createDelegate()` in their examples as it appears to be germane to using `clientContext.executeQueryAsync()`, which it is not.
- By convention a method with an `Async` suffix *should* return a promise, making the creation/resoltion of your own Deferreds unnecessary. However, Microsoft are again a little naughty in that `clientContext.executeQueryAsync()` *doesn't* follow the convention.

Secondly, asynchronously derived data can't be aggregated without first aggregating the promises that deliver the data. As given, the code in the question lacks any aggregation of promises. As this is jQuery, we would expect to see `jQuery.when()` somewhere in the code.

---

Regarding promisification, the neatest approach is always to promisify at the lowest level - in this case to write a reusable adaptor function for `clientContext.executeQueryAsync()`, which returns the desired promise. This will allow the higher level function `managementQuery()` to be simplified considerably.

Here's the promisifier :

```
clContext.executeQueryAsync_ = function() {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
        clContext.executeQueryAsync(function(sender,args) {
            dfrd.resolve({'sender':sender, 'args':args});
        }, function(sender,args) {
            dfrd.reject({'sender':sender, 'args':args})
        });
    }).promise();
};
```

Now, `managementQuery()` can be written devoid of Deferreds and devoid of `Function.createDelegate()`, as follows :

```
function managementQuery() {
    var query = clContext.executeQueryAsync_;  // If clContext.executeQueryAsync() returns a promise, then assign clContext.executeQueryAsync() instead.
    var promise1 = query(/* so params */);
    var promise2 = query(/* po params */);
    var promise3 = query(/* salesRep params */);

    // Now aggregate the three promises with $.when(), and chain .then() to handle the delivered data.
    return $.when(promise1, promise2, promise3)
    .then(function(soObj, poObj, salesRepObj) {
        // soObj, poObj and salesRepObj each have .sender and .args properties.
        // Now the required object can be created and returned 
        // to become the data delivered (in a promise) by managementQuery().
        return {
            'soObj': onSOQuerySucceeded(),
            'poObj': onPOQuerySucceeded(),
            'salesRepList': onSalesRepNamesQuerySucceeded()
        };
    });
}
```

And `managementMain()` can be written as follows :

```
function managementMain() {
    return managementQuery()
    .then(someOtherFunction) // someOtherFunction will be automagically passed the object created/returned above.
    .fail(function(e) {
        // Any promise rejection in managementQuery() or someOtherFunction will end up here.
        console.log(e);
        this.onQueryFailed();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Roamer, thanks very much for the detailed explanation and the extra input on the overall code. Really appreciate it as I'm new to this. I will implement it this way for my next code and will give feedback. This looks so much neater than what I have been doing. Thanks!!